# Refused boarding

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, indian-citizens

Hi I have been living in the UK for around 8 years.  Me and my children are German citizens,  my wife is an Indian citizen but she has a permanent residence card UK.  She booked a flight via Germany:  UK -> Frankfurt -> Munich -> India but they told my wife that she needs a transit visa for a flight to Germany.

Is that correct?

Comment: Err, are you asking if it was correct that your wife required a visa for a flight itinerary that went UK -> Frankfurt -> Munich -> India?

Comment: Your wife's permanent resident card would exempt her from the need for a Schengen short stay visa if and only if it is an "article 10" card.  An article 10 card will note that it is the "residence card of a family member of an EEA national."  If her card says that, then she was wrongly denied boarding.  If it doesn't, then she needs a Schengen visa, which should be issued free of charge under freedom-of-movement rules.  In any case, an airport transit visa will not suffice, because she would need to pass German immigration controls to fly from Frankfurt to Munich.